# Probability distribution for a three row matrix vector product

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

Consider a fixed (non-random) $3$ by $n$ matrix $M$ whose elements are chosen from $\{-1,1\}$.  <strike>Assume $n$ is even.</strike> I am trying work out what the probability mass function of $Mx$ is when $x$ is a random vector with elements chosen independently and uniformly at random from $\{-1,1\}$.

Each of the three elements of $y = Mx$ is distributed as a simple symmetric random walk. This is true no matter what $M$ is. We can therefore give the marginal probability distribution explicitly as:

$$P(y_i = k) = {n \choose (n+k)/2}\frac{1}{2^n},\;\; k \in \{-n, -n+2,\dots, n-2, n\}$$

However these marginal probabilities don't tell the whole story as there will typically be some dependence between the three elements of $y$ which depends on the values in $M$.

> Is it possible to write an explicit formulation for the probability
>   mass function of $y$?

I think we can set the first row of $M$ to be all $1$s without loss of generality which may  simplify the question.

**Example:**

In order to give a concrete worked example, let

$$M = \begin{pmatrix}
  -1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1\\
  -1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
  -1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}.$$

In this case the probability mass function is as follows. In each pair the first item is the vector $y$ and the second number is its probability.

```
[((-5, -1, 1), 0.03125), ((-3, -3, -1), 0.0625), ((-3, 1, -1), 0.03125), ((-3, 1, 3), 0.0625), ((-1, -5, -3), 0.03125), ((-1, -1, -3), 0.0625), ((-1, -1, 1), 0.125), ((-1, 3, 1), 0.0625), ((-1, 3, 5), 0.03125), ((1, -3, -5), 0.03125), ((1, -3, -1), 0.0625), ((1, 1, -1), 0.125), ((1, 1, 3), 0.0625), ((1, 5, 3), 0.03125), ((3, -1, -3), 0.0625), ((3, -1, 1), 0.03125), ((3, 3, 1), 0.0625), ((5, 1, -1), 0.03125)]
```

This is a follow-up to [Probability distribution for a matrix vector product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1593153/probability-distribution-for-a-matrix-vector-product) . It seems the first interesting case is in fact $3$ rows not $2$.

Comment: The assumption that $n$ is even is redundant, and in fact your example violates it.

Comment: @Justpassingby Thank you.  Question fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distribution does not change if we multiply all the entries of a single column by $-1,$ nor if we exchange two columns, so we can always bring $M$ into a form that starts with $w_1$ times the column $(1\ 1\ 1)^T$ followed by $w_2$ times the column $(1\ {-1}\ 1)^T$ followed by $w_3$ times $(1\ 1\ {-1})^T$ and ends with $w_4$ times the column $(1\ {-1}\ {-1})^T.$ The numbers $w_i$ are deterministic and known, and their sum is $n.$

$$M=\left(\begin{matrix}
1&1&\ldots&1&1&\ldots&1&1&\ldots&1&1\\
1&1&\ldots&-1&-1&\ldots&1&1&\ldots&-1&-1\\
1&1&\ldots&1&1&\ldots&-1&-1&\ldots&-1&-1\\
\end{matrix}\right)$$

Now $y=Mx$ is a linear combination of these four columns with random coefficients $c_1,$ $c_2,$ $c_3$ and $c_4.$

$$Mx=c_1\left(\begin{matrix}1\\1\\1\\ \end{matrix}\right)+c_2\left(\begin{matrix}1\\-1\\1\\ \end{matrix}\right)+c_3\left(\begin{matrix}1\\1\\-1\\ \end{matrix}\right)+c_4\left(\begin{matrix}1\\-1\\-1\\ \end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}c_1+c_2+c_3+c_4\\c_1-c_2+c_3-c_4\\c_1+c_2-c_3-c_4\\ \end{matrix}\right)$$

Here $c_1$ is the sum of the first $w_1$ components of the random vector $x,$ $c_2$ is the sum of the next $w_2$ components, $c_3$ the sum of the next $w_3$ and $c_4$ the sum of the last $w_4.$ The coefficients are independent and the distribution of $c_i$ is the fortune of a gambler after tossing a coin $w_i$ times. The explicit form of that distribution resembles the marginal distribution in your question:

$$P[c_i = j] = {w_i \choose (w_i+j)/2}\frac{1}{2^{w_i}},\;\; j \in \{-w_i, -w_i+2,\dots, w_i-2, w_i\}$$

The distribution $P\left[y=(k\ l\ m)^T\right]$ is then given by

$$P\left[(c_1+c_2+c_3+c_4=k)\wedge(c_1-c_2+c_3-c_4=l)\wedge(c_1+c_2-c_3-c_4=m)\right]$$

These three events are not independent but we can solve the three equations in four unknowns using an integer parameter $t$ (and knowing that $k,l,m$ and $n$ almost surely have the same parity):

$$\eqalign{
c_1&=t\\
c_2&=\frac{k+m}2-t\\
c_3&=\frac{k+l}2-t\\
c_4&=t-\frac{l+m}2\\
}$$

and we can rewrite our probability in terms of the independent $c_i$ as

$$\eqalign{
P\left[y=\left(
\begin{matrix}k\\ l\\ m\\ \end{matrix}
\right)\right]
&=\sum_tP\left[c_1=t\right]P\left[c_2=\frac{k+m}2-t\right]P\left[c_3=\frac{k+l}2-t\right]P\left[c_4=t-\frac{l+m}2\right]\\
&=2^{-n}\sum_t{w_1 \choose (w_1+t)/2}{w_2 \choose (w_2+\frac{k+m}2-t)/2}{w_3 \choose (w_3+\frac{k+l}2-t)/2}{w_4 \choose (w_4+t-\frac{l+m}2)/2}
}$$

The range of the summation index $t$ is in principle that of $c_1,$ i.e., the set $\{-w_1,-w_1+2,\ldots,w_1-2,w_1\}$ but in practice many of the terms will be zero because of restrictions on the other $c_i.$

Let us see how this works out in your example matrix $M.$ First flip the signs in columns 1, 3 and 4 so that the top row has only positive entries. Then move the fifth column to the front and we obtain

$$M=\left(
\begin{matrix}
1&1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&-1&-1\\
1&1&-1&-1&-1\\
\end{matrix}
\right)$$

so we have $n=5,$ $w_1=2,$ $w_2=0,$ $w_3=1$ and $w_4=2.$

We will repeat the second example from your numerical evaluation of the distribution, i.e., we compute $P[y=(-3\ -3\ -1)^T].$

We have $k=-3,$ $l=-3$ and $m=-1.$ From the fact that $c_2=0$ we see that the only value of $t$ contributing to the sum is $(k+m)/2=-2.$ So we get

$$P[y=(-3\ -3\ -1)^T]=2^{-5}{2 \choose 0}{0 \choose 0}{1 \choose 0}{2 \choose 1}=1/16,$$

which confirms your computation.

Comment: Thank you, this is very interesting but I am not sure I get all the details yet. Would it possible to show a small worked example please?

Comment: I made the derivation slightly more explicit, please ask specific questions about anything not clear yet. In the meantime I am working on an example.

Comment: Example done. Fire away with more questions now.

Comment: This is very interesting and the worked example is great. I will have to study it and come back with questions but thank you again.

Comment: What happens to the range of summation of $t$ if $w_1 =0$? That is if there is no all $1$ column.

Comment: Then the sum has a single term corresponding to $t=0.$

Comment: Do you think this approach extends to more rows? I ask because if I understand correctly the probability mass function (pmf) for $3$ by $n$ depends only on the values of $w_i$.  But consider square $n$ by $n$ matrices. Every singular matrix must have a different pmf to every non-singular matrix.   But simply knowing the number of copies of each types of column isn't sufficient to determine if a matrix is singular or not. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: The construction extends to more rows but it becomes less and less interesting as the number of rows $r$ grows large (it is robust against a large number of *columns* $n$). When solving the linear system for the $c_i$ the number of parameters (degrees of freedom of the solution) is $2^{r-1}-r.$ In particular if $r=n$ and it is a large number, working out the distribution of $y=Mx$ in this way is not essentially more efficient than brute force on all the possible assignments of $\pm1$ to the components of $x$ (there are $2^n$ such assignments).

Comment: Thank you. I meant something slightly different however. Let me ask something related but a little different. Consider only $n$ by $n$ matrices $M$ where the values of $w_i$ are either $0$ or $1$.  What does your method say about which of these matrices will have the same pmf as each other?

Comment: I agree that that is a little different :-) May I suggest that you make this a separate question? No need to offer bounties, just put a pointer in the comments here. For the moment, off the top of my head: you are asking for additional symmetries in the set of matrices $M$ beyond the two symmetries that I used, namely, flipping signs in whole columns and exchanging columns. Note that the permutation of the $w_i$ that results from exchanging two *rows* does not necessarily leave the pmf invariant (because we are *not* considering permutations of the components of $y$).

Comment: Follow up question posted to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1604135/which-matrices-give-the-same-probability-mass-function . Thank you.